# php imagick JPEG2000 compression increases in filesize

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am using imagick php extension to create **.webp** and **.jp2** files from .jpg and compress the image during the process. I'm getting good results for .webp images, but having some issues with .jp2.

This is my code to create **webp**:

```
<?php
$img = new Imagick("test.jpg");
$img->setImageFormat("webp");
$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(50);
$img->writeImage("test.webp");
?>
```

And this works fine, my webp is almost 90% decreased in file size compared to jpg. But using the same technique for JPEG2000 (jp2), I have an increase in file size of around 30%.

This is the code I'm using for **jp2**:

```
<?php
$img = new Imagick("test.jpg");
$img->setImageFormat("jp2");
$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG2000);
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(50);
$img->writeImage("test.jp2");
?>
```

I tried many different images as a sourcefile (compressed and uncompressed), all had the same result. Any insights to what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you take 3 lines to read an image instead of just `$image = new Imagick('test.jpg');`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @MarkSetchell. That was a redundant leftover from previous attempts. :) Will change it in the question... Basicly, just trying to create compressed webp and jp2 files from base jpg file.

Comment: Maybe you can share your input image in case it has some feature that is upsetting the compression scheme.

Comment: Quality works differently in JPEG2000, see the `defines` starting `jp2:XXX` here https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php In PHP Imagick, you might want `$imagick->setOption('jp2:quality', 40); `

Comment: Yes.. That's it. Thanks! Add it as an aswer so I can check it as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sufficiently familiar with JPEG2000 to offer any useful explanation, and would prefer if someone else can explain it better, so please don't rush to *"accept"* this answer.

For the moment though, note that quality works differently in JPEG2000, see the defines starting jp2:XXX [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php).

In PHP Imagick, you could implement the equivalent `defines` with:

```
$imagick->setOption('jp2:quality', 40);
```